# Possible to create Magento orders while authorize.net in test mode?

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Will Magento allow orders to be created with either authorize.net set to TEST mode on the Magento side or the authorize.net website?

We see orders in processing mode that were put in when we thought authorize.net was in TEST mode. The orders were made using real credit cards, not the test 4222* card numbers.

I thought when either side was in TEST mode, Magento would throw up a dialog box when submitting a order, saying that authorize.net was in test mode.

Basically, is it possible to place an order all the way if authorize.net is set to TEST mode on the Magento site or authorize.net site?

Comment: Yep, the order will be created if you have test mode on.  I am only familiar with Magento 1.3 (not newer versions), but I am pretty sure that having authorize.net in test mode works just like if it was not in test mode, except for the fact that authorize.net doesn't actually do any real credit card processing. In the Magento interface you won't notice a difference.

Comment: This should be an answer, not a comment

Comment: Yeah, you are right John.  I made an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, the order will be created if you have test mode on. I am only familiar with Magento 1.3 (not newer versions), but I am pretty sure that having authorize.net in test mode works just like if it was not in test mode, except for the fact that authorize.net doesn't actually do any real credit card processing. In the Magento interface you won't notice a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When Authorize.Net is in test mode the trans_id is always 0. So you cannot do "Prior Authorize and Capture" transactions (nor void and credit transactions).

In other words, if you have Magento configured for "Authorize Only" then you will be able to place an order but you will not be able to invoice that order since the trans_id is 0. However, if you have Magento configured for "Authorize and Capture" then it will work okay.

The way I tested since I'm suing "Authorize Only" was I started in test mode to make sure things were communicating and then switch to live mode and just voided or credited those orders after testing. I created a $0.01 product so that I didn't go over my limit on my personal credit card :)

Comment: Also, that 4222... credit card number allows you to test Authorize.net's various response reason codes. The dollar amount represents the response reason code. You can also use 4111111111111111 in test mode which is just a generic Visa test number and you can use that with any dollar amount.